# no matching constructor for initialization of 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')

Tags: c++, string, c++11, clang

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

class Foo { 
public:
    operator string() const { return n; }
    string n {"foo"};
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    string s {Foo{}};
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles using gcc 4.8.3, but it does not compile using clang 3.5, can someone tell me what's wrong with it?

I got an error like this:

```
main.cpp:45:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')
    string s {Foo{}};
           ^ ~~~~~~~
```

clang --version:

```
clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final 216961)
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
```

Thanks

Comment: One obviously possibility: you've failed to include `<string>` (and gcc happens to include `<string>` from some other header you have included).

Comment: It would be great if we could get the full file (with includes and all) to narrow down the possibilities of human error in interpreting your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a clang bug. According to the rules for list-initialization in [dcl.init.list]:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of type *cv* `U`, where `U` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a character array and [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, [...]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see
>     below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.
> - [...]

`T` is a class type, so we consider the [`basic_string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). #7 in that list (the copy constructor) is an applicable, viable constructor and so it should be chosen. At that point, these expressions should be equivalent:

```
struct Foo {
    operator std::string() const { return "hello"; }
};

std::string s{Foo{}};  // error
std::string s(Foo{});  // OK
std::string s = Foo{}; // OK
```

For some reason though, in the list-initialization case, clang complains that there is:

> no known conversion from `Foo` to `const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &` for 1st argument

There is though, so I filed this as [LLVM Bug 23658](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23658).

Comment: I did it also https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23657 I haven't seen your edit.

Comment: doesn't the `const` qualifier of the conversion operator makes it not applicable to a temporary created object?

Comment: @bolov Nope. It's a `const` qualifier, not a `&` qualifier.

Comment: Program in the OP compiles with clang++3.7 tip-of-trunk and libc++

Comment: I noted the successful compilation with ToT, and closed #23658 as a duplicate of #23657.

Answer (score 0):

I guess too It is clang bug. One of the solutions to remove this kind of error is to use defined variables to call a function. For example, if I want to call this function : `myFunction(int& a, string& b)` instead of called it by using this call by value `myFunction(2, "Hello")`, I will do this `int a = 2; string b = "Hello"; myFunction(a, b);` and boom clang will not show this kind of error anymore. Thanks for this question.