# C++ error: no matching constructor for initialization of "my:Library" with Clang 11.0.3

Tags: c++, macos, constructor, compiler-errors, clang

I have been several post with something similar to my problem but I can't figure out how to solve it in my implementation.

It's about a custom exception classes that compile perfectly in Linux with gcc 9, but in MacOs (Catalina) with Clang 11.0.3 fails dramatically.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdexcept>
        
    class Exception : public std::runtime_error
  {
    public:
        Exception() : std::runtime_error("mt library error") {}
        Exception(const std::string& what_arg) : std::runtime_error(what_arg) {}
    };
    
    
    /// Division by zero exception.
    class ZeroDivide : public Exception
    {
    public:
        ZeroDivide() : Exception("Division by near-zero value") {}
    };
```

When compile in MacOS I get the error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'mt::Exception'
    ZeroDivide() : Exception("Division by near-zero value") {}
                   ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and different notes like:

```
candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [36]' to 'const mt::Exception' for 1st argument
```

and other errors derived from the first one when I try to throw the exception like:

```
Exception("Normalizing interval is ill defined")
```

I have seen some examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461583/no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-of-string-aka-basic-stringchar) of how could fix the problem but I can not figure out how to reimplement mine in order to make it work in MacOs

Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

As the project is big, I have created a repository [here](https://github.com/abiudrodas/test_question_stackoverflow.git) with a minimal example to reproduce the error, you just have to compile following this steps

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, thanks I have added a minimal reproducible example to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your compiler is complaining that it won't automatically convert the hardcoded string `"Division by near-zero value"` that you provide to the constructor of `Exception` from `const char*` to `const std::string&`.

I have no access to macos at the moment but my guess is that you could fix it by constructing a `std::string` at the place of calling the base constructor:

```
ZeroDivide() : Exception(std::string("Division by near-zero value")) {}
```

Another possible fix is to define a constructor in `Exception` that takes a `const char*`:

```
Exception(const char* what_arg) : std::runtime_error(what_arg) {}
```

This might be the better fix, as [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) actually has both constructors for `const char*` and for `const std::string&`.

Comment: at the moment, the first options doesn't work, however the second one solves the problem. Thanks